# My "Enemy" in my pygame has the same image as my player

Tags: python, pygame

I think it has something to do with the movement of my other character, and that it is something wrong with the `Screen.blit` But I don't fully know

I also checked if it was something wrong with the image I am using myself and there isn't anything wrong with it.

```
import pygame

# Intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# Skjerm Oppløsning?
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Tittel og logo
pygame.display.set_caption("Båtisens Herre")
icon = pygame.image.load('img.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# bakgrunn
background = pygame.image.load("bakgrunn.png")

# Spiller
playerImg = pygame.image.load('King Arthur2.png')
playerX = 100
playerY = 200

# enemy
enemyImg = pygame.image.load('Black knight1.png')
enemyX = 200
enemyY = 300
enemyX_change = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))



# game loop

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        playerX -= 4
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerX += 4

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0,))


    # RGB (rød, grønt blått)
    screen.fill((248, 58, 226))


    # Bakgrunn(2)
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0,))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You use `playerImg` in the `player` function as in the `enemy` function

Answer (score 2):

You're blitting the same image both for the enemy and the player:

```
def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))
```

This should reference the photo `enemyImg` to `blit` the image of the enemy instead:

```
def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg, (x, y))
```

Good luck on your Lord of the Boat Ice game.